# Cannot use dlmread to read the whole tab-delimited file

Tags: matlab, csv

I am still new to MATLAB. I am going to read a file containing lines with tab-delimited entries. Below is the example:

```
   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.000   3.000
```

The whole file is [in this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63868563/MOD_H13). When I try using dlmread like this:

```
entry = dlmread(filepath,'\t',4,0);
```

It only reads 3294 instead of 125172 entries starting from the 5th line. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)? Why are you using `4,0` ?

Comment: The entries I would like to read start from 5th line. I have read that online document many times but still do not know where the error comes from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63868563/MOD_H13) you uploaded, there are *250344 entries*, not 125172, starting from the *5th* row to the end.
`dlmread(filepath,'',4,0);` reads all of them. (3294*76=250344).

**Why does `\t` not work here?**

 This is because the spaces in your file are not really <kbd>tab</kbd> spaces. Those are some simple spaces.